# error after installing npm package ,You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, craco

I've installed the npm package @yaireo/tagify v4.16.4 however when I try to start my react app I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.js 594:33
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (594:33)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|           headerRef = this.dropdown.getHeaderRef(),
|           footerRef = this.dropdown.getFooterRef();
>       newHeaderElem && headerRef?.parentNode.replaceChild(newHeaderElem, headerRef);
|       newFooterElem && footerRef?.parentNode.replaceChild(newFooterElem, footerRef);
|     },
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "portal_service",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "1.1.0",
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.7.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.16.5",
    "@casl/ability": "3.4.0",
    "@casl/react": "1.0.4",
    "@craco/craco": "6.4.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "5.13",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "5.13",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "5.13",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "5.13",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.11",
    "@okta/okta-react": "3.0.1",
    "@react-hook/resize-observer": "1.2.5",
    "@tisoap/react-flow-smart-edge": "1.0.1",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "4.13.1",
    "ant-design-pro": "2.3.2",
    "antd": "4.16.13",
    "antd-img-crop": "3.16.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.1",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "0.7.0",
    "firebase": "9.6.1",
    "google-map-react": "1.1.7",
    "jsoneditor": "9.7.4",
    "jsoneditor-react": "3.1.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "mobx": "5.15.7",
    "mobx-react": "5.4.4",
    "mobx-react-lite": "1.5.2",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.34",
    "papaparse": "5.3.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "rc-progress": "2.3.0",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "13.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.7.4",
    "react-circle-flags": "^0.0.17",
    "react-click-outside": "3.0.1",
    "react-cropper": "2.1.8",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-flow-renderer": "10.0.4",
    "react-google-login": "5.1.20",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "6.12.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "3.1.44",
    "react-quill": "1.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "5.2.2",
    "react-top-loading-bar": "1.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "7.1.0",
    "slugify": "1.4.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3",
    "superagent": "7.0.1",
    "superagent-promise": "1.1.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "craco start",
    "start:withMockServer": "npx concurrently --kill-others 'yarn run mock-server' 'yarn start'",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test --env=jsdom",
    "test:withLiveCoverage": "npx concurrently --kill-others 'yarn test --coverage --watchAll' 'npx live-server coverage/lcov-report'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "mock-server": "npx json-server src/utils/mockData.js --port 4000 --watch --delay 1500",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "lint-fix": "eslint ./src --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "2.0.2",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.6.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "faker": "4.1.0",
    "husky": "1.3.1",
    "jest-styled-components": "6.3.4",
    "json-server": "0.14.2",
    "lint-staged": "8.2.1",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "6.1.1",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "source-map-explorer": "1.8.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css}": [
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "cracoConfig": "config/craco.config.js",
  "resolutions": {
    "//": "See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

We are using craco to run our react app. The craco config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['babel-plugin-styled-components'],
    ],
  },
  // Disables react-scripts's own ESLint from running on every compilation. This prevents a very long compilation time.
  // We don't need react-scripts to run its own ESLint every time, because we have our own ESLint configuration to use with "npm run lint"
  eslint: {
    enable: false,
  },
};
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix the error? We've tried different versions of the npm package but all of them throw a similar error. We really need this package for a feature I am working on so there is no option for an alternative.